# SSIS: ForEach Loop Container: Looping through Excel sheets with Uniforn columns but different sheet names

Tags: excel, foreach, ssis

If all data and columns are uniform in Excel but each worksheet has different names, will this disrupt my `ForEach Loop Container`?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a variable of string type and assign the sheetname value to it dynamically then it won't affect your Foreach Container.

Please make sure that the variable name ends with "$".

So put some logic to retrieve sheetname first and then assign it to variable.

If you are interested in getting sheetname list, then follow this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403358.aspx) article.

Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345182.aspx) is the way to loop through Excel Files and Tables by Using a Foreach Loop Container